# When returning a list of items in an array, I am getting Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument in Textmate - but NOT IRB

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, textmate

***See updates below***

So this is my code:

```
def add_category(new_url)
    new_url + '/web/'
end

url = 'http://www.someurl.com'

def modify_my_list(list)
    puts "The number of links in this list are: #{list.count}"
    list.each do |i, k|
          k = add_category(k)
              puts k
    end
end

modify_my_list(list)
```

Basically what I am doing is going through a list of links that are on a specific URL and processing them.

But the output I am seeing (i.e. the list of links) is less than what I know I should be seeing.

In other words, the number of links that are being printed on my screen is less than the amount that is printed from `list.count`.

This is the error I am getting:

```
Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument

method write    in my-search.rb at line 83   =>     puts k
method puts in my-search.rb at line 83
method modify_my_list   in my-search.rb at line 83
method each in my-search.rb at line 81   =>     list.each do |i, k|
method modify_my_list   in my-search.rb at line 81
at top level    in my-search.rb at line 87 => modify_city_list(list)
```

Thoughts?

**Update**

When I do a `puts list.inspect` it outputs the entire array and doesn't throw an error. The error seems to come once I start iterating through the array.

**Update 2**

So I am encountering this error when I run it in Textmate. However, I took the output from `list.inspect` and did it in IRB. Then I modified the list elements in IRB and it works without giving me an error. Could it be Textmate throwing this error and not Ruby or my script?

Answer (score 2):

What are you passing in as list?

I think it should be

```
list.each do |k|
```

or

```
list.each_with_index do |k, i|
```

If list is a two dimensional array a simplified version of your code would be:

```
b = [['a1','b1'], ['a2','b2']]

b.each do |k, v|
    v = v + 'xz'
    puts v
end
```

Can you try this on irb to see if it works for you?

Edit:

Have you tried this?

```
list.each do |k|
   k[1] = add_category(k[1])
   puts k[1]
end
```

Comment: I am passing in a 2D array. So the first option won't work, and this is what I get when I try `each_with_index` - `TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum`.

Comment: Could you post an example of the array definition with data?

Comment: Well...it simply looks like this: `list = my_list(url)`. The data would be something like: `list[0][0] = Honda, list[0][1] = 'www.honda.com'`.

Comment: Hav youe tried to put the value of k before calling add_category() to see what you're passing in?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I just did it, and it is modifying the URL properly. The before value of `k` is the regular url - `www.honda.com` and the after value of `k` is `www.honda.com/web`. So that part is working properly - which I had suspected.

Comment: Sure does, see the result here: `> b1xz
> b2xz
 => [["a1", "b1"], ["a2", "b2"]]`

Comment: When do you get the error? Is it when iterating on a specific element of the list? If it is, are you certain this is a string too?

Comment: No...it doesn't generate the error on a specific element. It seems to be that it hits it after 500 items have been outputted. For instance, I changed the return value of `add_category` to an array of two or more values and so it doubles up the output of the links. So the point at which it stops printing out is a different link than if I had just returned 1 single value. But both output roughly 520ish lines.

Comment: The thing is, it's not EXACTLY 520 lines. For instance in 1 case, it outputs 523 lines and in another it outputs 569 lines. So not sure why that is.

Comment: The k and i are transposed in the each_with_index.

Comment: @pguardiario they are if you are used to naming your index "i", but they can actually be named like that. Changed it to avoid further confusions. Thanks!

Comment: I hope you're not saying you're used to naming keys 'i' and indexes 'k' :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it makes more sense to just do:

```
urls = list.map{|url| url + '/web/'}
```

Comment: Where do I do this? In my add_category method?

Comment: No, that replaces both methods.

Comment: I keep getting this: `TypeError: can't convert String into Array` around the entire line. Thoughts?

Comment: It means one of your urls is an array. Maybe you want to flatten the list first.

Comment: It's a two dimensional array. Will that change anything here?

Comment: Ok...I added another local variable to the block, and it worked. I am still getting that Error though. It also outputs 574 items, even though there should be 719.

Comment: Yes, it won't work with a 2d array. I can't really tell what you're trying to do at this point or why you would name a 2d array 'list'

Comment: Well...I am taking it one step at a time. Basically, the 2D array is an array of links. Where in [0][0] is the name of the link, and [0][1] is the href. So I am cycling through them and modifying just the links which are stored (I don't want to modify the names of the links). But that still doesn't tell me why I am getting this error :)

Comment: I updated the question with more details of my investigations.

Comment: in that case: list.map{|arr| [arr[0], [arr[1] + '/web/']}

Comment: That does the same thing, but I am still getting the error in Textmate.